# Is it possible to create an item which doesn't have a partition key for a GSI in dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb table. The table's partition key is `id`. One of its GSI has a partition key: `type`. When I create an item on dynamodb table, it requires me fill in the `type` field for GSI. Is it possible to make `type` as optional? That means there are some items I don't want them to be saved in GSI.

When I am using `aws sdk` client, I am able to put an item without the GSI partition key. It works as long as the item has table partition key. But when I work on AWS dyanmodb console, it always asks me to set GSI partition key. I think this is an issue with AWS console.

Answer (score 2):

You can create [sparse indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html), but they are based on sort keys, not partition keys:

> For any item in a table, DynamoDB writes a corresponding index entry **only if the index sort key value is present** in the item. If the sort key doesn't appear in every table item, the index is said to be **sparse**.

What's more GSI are **sparse by default**:

> Global secondary indexes are sparse by default. When you create a global secondary index, you specify a partition key and **optionally a sort key**. Only items in the base table that contain those attributes appear in the index.

So back to your question, partition key is required. If you want to use sparse index, you can do this by having having GSI with **`type` as a sort key**.

This way, items that don't have `type` attribute, **won't be present** in sparse GSI.

Comment: I have a GSI already. The problem is that dynamodb doesn't allow me to create an item which doesn't have GSI partition key.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao It does not allow you, because you can't do this. You can have only sparse GSI when a sort key is missing.

Comment: If we create a GSI with `type` as a sort key, what the partition key I should give? I don't need any other keys. The query interface for clients to call only require one parameter `type`.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao This is application specific. If you don't want to use sort key, maybe keep a separate table with references to main table for selected items that you want? Otherwise, it seams that your table may need redesigning if you have items where you don't want a partition key :-(

Comment: I have items which don't have a partition in GSI. The items do have partition key in main table. I don't know why it is not allowed in dynamodb.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao I think the reason is [following](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.Projections) "The partition key and sort key of the table are always projected into the index;" Since the partition key of the primary table is always projected, you must have it. Sort key can be optional, thus producing sparse GSI.

Comment: I did some tests and found an interesting result. Actually when I use `aws sdk` nodejs client, I can put an item to the table without specifying the index partition key. But dynamodb table console doesn't allow me to do that.

Comment: I updated my question, I think this is an issue with AWS dynamodb console.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao Thanks for letting me know. But then what is your partition key? So you are able to create GSI without partition key nor sort key?

Comment: No this is not what I mean. What I mean is I am able to create an item which doesn't include GSI partition key. In my case, it only has `id` but no `type`.

Comment: My question is not about creating GSI. It is about create an item which doesn't have GSI partition key.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao I guess that my answer is incorrect then. I can remove it. You can add the answer to your own question then :-)

Comment: no worries. Your stuff is a good point and please keep it which will benefit other people